# Are file descriptors thread safe

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, file-descriptor

Are File Descriptors thread safe? I can't seem to find information on this and I don't really know how to test it.

Lets say I have a socket, if two threads attempt to write to it at once will it either.

1. Crash the program
2. Block one of the threads until it is ready
3. Both immediately continue and the writes are queued by the OS
4. Something I didn't think off

It's a burning question of mine. I know how to fix it if they aren't threadsafe, like handle it with Libevent. But it would be nice to know the answer.

Comment: You have to make it thread safe: use mutex to handle the concurrency.

Comment: I suppose [you haven't read this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/file-descriptors-and-multithreaded-progr/212001285) which comes as the first result googling the title of your question.

Comment: Your box has one comms stack and one system disk.  It has many processes, each of which must have at least one thread.  Some of those processes use disk and network connections.  Now draw a conclusion:)

Comment: And this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17432052/174614 really gives you all you need to know.