# using mutex or not for concurrent files sending over tcp sockets

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp, concurrency

I have developped a multithreaded system that creates a child process for each client request to read and send files to clients via tcp sockets.

I have difficulties to see if using a mutex for every file reading is going to better the performance, or is it better to let child processes read files concurrently from the hard disk without using mutexes.

The files sizes are 500 ko in average and we estimated the simultanuous tcp connections to be at max 2000 per minute.

PS : the program reads each file in chucks of 2000 bytes, sends each buffer and loop until transmission is finished

Comment: Let the OS and the disk driver and the disk and the network do the mutexing. Don't try to help. Use a mutex when *you* need it.

Comment: agreed thanks, but wouldn't it exhaust the server resources to have too much concurrent connections reading files at the same time. woudldn't the hard drive slow down and crush in the long run ?

Comment: If you agree I don't know why you are even asking. You might want to limit the number of active concurrent connections, but that doesn't have anything to do with mutexes.

Comment: Thanks but the disrespect was unecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been approaching these sorts of issues as: which operations are being performed on which resources by whom?

Some of the operations being performed are:

- reads on files (potentially shared?)

  - Does the OS (linux?) guarantee that file reads are threadsafe? **Yes** it [looks like it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432052/594589) . If this is truly the case (something i'm not super familiar with) then coordinating mutex's across process for file access will be unnecessary overhead.
- Writes to TCP per proccess

  - This shouldn't be any issue with concurrency because each process handles its own TCP connection

If the link posted reflects reality than there shouldn't be any need for cross process coordination (mutexes)

Comment: Hi, yes my server is on Linux and i do utilize syscall functions for file descriptor access which are thread safe in all mainstream UNIX-like OSes. So i won't need the mutexes. Thank you !