# Context switch in the middle of a system call

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system

Assume we have 2 threads in the process.
now we run the following code:

```
read(fd, buf, 10);
```

where fd is some file descriptor which is shared among the threads (say static), and buf is an array which is not shared among the threads (local variable).

now, assume that the file is 1KB and the first 10 chars in the file are "AAAAAAAAAA" and all the rest are 'B's. ("BBBBBB.....").

now If we have only one processor, what the output of the bufs are if ill print them in each thread?

I know the answer is that one of the arrays will always have only A's and the other only B's, but I don't fully understand why, because I think that there could be a context switch in the middle of this system-call (read) and then both of the buf's will have A's in them.

Is it even possible for a context switch to occur in the middle of a system-call? and if so what do you think will buf's could have at the end of the execution?

Comment: The path through kernels, I/O request blocks, drivers, hardware interfaces, drive controllers and caches is long and tortuous.  Also, sufficient locking is applied to manage such 'overlapping' requests.  On every system I've worked on, it would appear to the user threads as if the calls were serialized, no matter when any interrupt occurred that might change the set of running threads.

Comment: Keep in mind most disk reads are in much bigger byte granularity. Even though you read 10 bytes, most probably 512 bytes or more are read.

Comment: @MartinJames Can you please post a full explanation about why this calls will be serialized although the interrupts?

Comment: I don't know about the `read` function, but It appears that [the `write` function was not thread-safe](https://lwn.net/Articles/180387/) in linux in the year 2006. I have no idea what the situation is now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C read and thread safety (linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431813/c-read-and-thread-safety-linux)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel  Actually writes are thread-safe by POSIX definition as there are no partial writes.  However one of two simultaneous writes to the same file descriptor may be lost unless the user serializes them.  That's the condition described in the article.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Prior to kernel version 3.14, the file offset for `read` and `write` were not updated atomically as they should be, according to the Linux man pages.

Answer (score 0):

Modern disks cannot perform reads and writes at 10-byte granularity and instead perform reads and writes in units of sectors, traditionally 512 bytes for hard disk drives (HDDs).

 Copying 10 characters to thread buffer happen very fast, before context switch though not guaranteed.

A simple program to get a feeling would be to have 2 threads printing to same console, one prints `+` and the other `-`. Check how many `+` before first `-`.
Anyway, on to the original question, change the size of the array to 1024 and have 1024 `A`'s to start with and you will most probably see the difference.